# How to schedule VMs to startup and shutdown

Tags: hyper-v, startup

I'm running several VMs (Mainly windows XP) on a 2008 server under Hyper-V.
I'd like to automatically schedule some of these machines to startup and shutdown according to a schedule.  To limit availability to the times when people are supposed to be in the office to log into them.
How can this be achieved??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So basically it is pretty easy with PowerShell

1. Install PS
2. Get the library written for managing VMs http://www.codeplex.com/PSHyperv
3. Write your PS script which looks like something like this:

   . c:\whatever\hyperv.ps1

   Stop-VM XXX

   Start-VM XXX
4. Schedule it http://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html

HTH

Comment: Thanks - It took me a while to get powershell up and running, now I've been using it for a few days I've got the startup/shutdown running smoothly.  Great Answer!